# Dynamic binding for one than one interlinked controls

Tags: xforms, orbeon

Is it possible to provide dynamic binding for repeating controls which has dependency on corresponding repeating controls. Consider the following scenario.

```
    Principal1  Rate1
    Principal2  Rate2
    Principal3  Rate3
    Principal4  Rate4
```

In this scenario the Rate1 is dependent on Principal1 such as (Rate1 <  Principal1 ). Similar conditions stays for Rate2,Rate3,Rate4 as well. Is it possible to impound this constraint using a generalized bind or is it necessary to put binds and constraints for each individual Rate control? Kindly advise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into XPath relative paths.

You can write the constraint for the repeated areas relative path. I presume Principal1 and Rate1 are going to be repeated together.

```
<repeated-section>
   <principal>
   <rate>
</repeated-section>
```

We have a constraint placed on the principal field that states if the rate (within the same repeat) is greater than 100, the principal field is valid

```
<xforms:bind nodeset="instance('instance')/repeated-section/principal"     
     constraint="../rate &gt; 100" />
```

**Note:** Also make sure not to use binds within repeated sections.  Use `ref=""` instead and state the input's relative path in relation to the repeated section

Comment: the principal and rate control is going be repeated but Principal1  Rate1 is unique and different Principal2  Rate2
and same is the case for others. The commonality among these controls is the constraint applied on it. Is it possible to apply these constraints to all these nodes without writing repeating code for each node (Rate1,Rate2,Rate3,Rate4)



)

Comment: Yes that is why you use the relative path. Each principal and rate pair will be evaluated separately.  Principal1 will only evaluate against Rate1, and Principal2 will only evaluate against Rate2, etc...